# Mapping out 3D points with QGIS2threejs

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, 3d, qgis2threejs

I have some points I would like to map out in 3D. The points were gotten from a GPS module athat was attached to a Raspberry Pi.

This is the settings I used before starting qgis2threejs:

[image]

This was the output it gave me:

[image]

The purple vector building's settings are as shown:

[image]

The issue is that the altitude values for the pink spheres were taken on ground level. So why is it floating in the air like that?

Does the CRS matter? I enabled on the fly CRS transformation already. The land that I am mapping out is relatively flat, around 20-40m elevation from sea level.

I am not understanding this problem! Desperate for help!

## UPDATE

I found the [problem](http://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.org/en/docs-release/ExportSettings.html#vector)!

The problem is that the Z coordinate mode adds up the height

"relative to DEM" + "Altitude" + Addend

Is it possible to remove the "relative to DEM" to the equation?

Answer (score 2):

Hi since your points are from a GPS track I am guessing that they have a Z-value field or an elevation field.

When you configure the ThreeJS plugin in QGIS you should have the following options for the Z coordinate settings area:

- Relative to DEM
- Absolute value

I did an example with point data and line data that have an attribute called elevation. I configured the ThreeJS plugin to use the elevation values as absolute values, and not relative to DEM.[image]

Once this is done the results look really good: 
[image]

Also consider upgrading your QGIS ThreeJS plugin if it is not updated to the latest version.